# Regular Expression for CSV with numbers

Tags: regex, string, csv

I'm looking for some regular expression to help parse my CSV file.

The file has lines of

```
number,number
number,number
Comment I want to skip
number,number
number,number
```

Ex:

```
319,5446
564425,87
Text to skip
27,765564
```

I read each line into a string and I wanted to use some regular express to make sure the line matches the pattern of (number,number). If not then don't use the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution:

^\d+,\d+$

Comment: Thanks... let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you can use below RegExp for a comma-separated list of any number of digits:

```
^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Little extension if you want to match a comma separated list of 1-5 stars ⭐: `^[12345](,[12345])*$`

Answer (score 1):

This should match your numbers and line start/end:

```
^\d+,\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Which language do you want to do this in? 
In perl:

```
read in each line of the csv file and save to $line
if($line !~ m/\d+, \d+/) {
    Do whatever you are going to do with the line with 2 numbers
}
```

In Java use [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/) site to help:

```
 read in each line of the csv file and save to variable line
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\d+, \d+"); // remove space if it isn't in file
 Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
 if (m.find()) {
    //it matches
 }
```

Comment: @Bernie Perez I added to the above answer to handle Java specifically.

Comment: Your examples will not match because of the whitespace after the comma... The OP example had no whitespace around the comma.

Comment: then remove the space, as I commented at the end of the line. So instead have "\d+,\d+" The \d means it matches to a number, the + means it matches it 1 or more times (so it matches to 3 or 333333). Thus this line mean it matches one or more numbers then a comma and then one or more numbers again. The line in the code above matches if there are numbers then a comma followed by a space and then more numbers. The below website, also in link above, describes this in more detail in regards to Java.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/